# Execute .sh file in ubuntu on windows

Tags: c++, bash, shell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have created a file, 1.sh, as

> c++ -c file1.cpp
>
> c++ file1.o -o file1

And I tried to execute it on bash Ubuntu on windows. It tells me

> : No such file or directory
>
> c++: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

However, if I execute

> c++ -c file1.cpp
>
> c++ file1.o -o file1

directly, the file (file1.cpp) can be complied normally.

My question is, what is the reason .sh file does not work and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like c++ is an available command in your system. You can try with absolute path of your command within script in place of c++. You can find it using command `which c++`.

Comment: I tried to modify .sh file as /usr/bin/c++ -c file1.cpp
/usr/bin/c++ file1.o -o file1 , still told me : No such file or directory

Comment: Check `/usr/bin` is part of your environmental variable `PATH`. You can check it by using following command, `echo $PATH` if it is not please include it by modifying in `.profile` file in your home directory.

Comment: `c++` might be an alias to `g++`, which your script might not understand.  Perhaps you're not executing it with the shell you thought you were, or the config for a terminal is different to the config for an executed script.

Comment: echo $PATH gives me /bin:/usr/bin/c++. Still, execute ./2.sh, give me : No such file or directory

Comment: @paddy, c++/g++ give the same result..

Comment: So, your script is executable?  _that_ error message looks like a permissions problem.  Try `chmod +x ./2.sh`.  And get in the habit of putting `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of your _bash_ scripts.

Comment: I tried chmod 777 2.sh and #!/bin/bash on .bashrc. Still the same :(

Comment: Do you have header file ?

Comment: @DreamInBox, no header file.

Comment: For me, the error message looks like whether `c++` cannot find the `file1.cpp`. How could this happen? Probably, if the the shell script uses a different current working directory (although I don't know why it should). However, to check this out you could insert a line before c++: `echo "$PWD"`.

Comment: How do you start your `.sh` file? From the bash or using a double click on it? If you don't start it from the bash you should check the working directory in you .sh file, i.e. output it to the console so you can verify that you'r in the expected directory.

Comment: Run `cat -vet 1.sh` and look if there are any `^M` characters in it. Native Windows text editors will put a CRLF at the end of each line, but Linux only wants LF at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would like to write this as comment but there is not this formatting available. (I will delete this answer when it becomes obsolete.)

I just tried this (with g++ on cygwin's bash):

```
$ g++ -c nothing.cc
g++: error: nothing.cc: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$
```

Of course, where is no file `nothing.cc` in my current working directory...

So, it might be that my guess (C++ is running in the wrong working directory when started from shell script) might be reasonable...

As I already suggested: insert a

```
echo "$PWD"
```

at the beginning of your shell script to be sure.

*Update:*

Out of curiosity, I tried this also (cygwin, bash again):

```
$ c++ -c nothing.cc
c++: error: nothing.cc: No such file or directory
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$
```

Now, it looks very similar to the OP.

The only fact that's puzzling me: The error message of the OP looks like whether the compiler didn't get any input:

```
$ c++
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$
```

but I believe that's not the case because in the OP it starts with 
`: No such file or directory`.
Thus, it rather looks like there is missing some text...